# different result between phpinfo.php and php-v

Tags: php

i was using appserv 5.8
and in my phpinfo.php the php version was 5.6.26
now i installed laravel5.5
and its required phpversion 7 
so i changed the php version to 7 from 5 
now in my phpinfo.php

```
PHP Version 7.0.11
```

and when i write in the command

```
php -v
```

its give me

```
PHP 5.6.26 (cli) (built: Sep 15 2016 18:12:07)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

and i cant install the packages with laravel 5.5 bc the version in command line is 5.6 not 7 
but when i check in phpinfo its 7
i have read something thats the command php -v tack the version from php-cli 
so  how can i change the php -v to be 7.0.1 as phpinfo.php
thanks ..

Comment: What OS are you on? How did you upgrade php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

phpinfo.php shows what version of PHP Apache is using. -v shows what's in your $PATH.

If you're on a Mac I recommend using homebrew to install php 7 as described [here](https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-upgrade-your-version-of-php-to-7-0-on-macos-sierra-e1bfdea55a63?source=linkShare-67ba9eb453cd-1505113242)

To clarify, [PHP can be run in 3 ways](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.general.php): behind a web server, for command line scripting, and for GUI building. You have 2 versions: the web server one, which Apache is calling and invoking `phpinfo.php`, and [PHP-CLI](http://www.php-cli.com/), which is invoked from the command line with `php -v`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your PHP CLI version is different than the PHP web version. Upgrade your PHP CLI package.

Answer (score 2):

You have two PHP binaries installed. In my Mac OSX:

```
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php

$ /usr/local/bin/php -v
PHP 7.0.20 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2017 09:47:44) ( NTS )
```

And in same machine:

```
$ whereis php
/usr/bin/php

$ /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb  7 2017 16:18:37)
```

You should put /usr/local/bin in your PATH. Edit ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Open a new terminal and check your php version.

Answer (score 0):

> For me(Windows) changing CLI version also didn't work, finally
> changing PHP version at  **Environment Variable PATH** worked!!