# Switch to php 8 Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed php 8.0.15 on my Debian 10 (GCP vm)

php -v

```
PHP 8.0.15 (cli) (built: Jan 29 2022 07:37:39) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.15, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

But my wordpress site still on php 7.4
I used a2dismod, a2enmod, apache2 restart - its doesnt help.
What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [different result between phpinfo.php and php-v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018531/different-result-between-phpinfo-php-and-php-v)

Comment: I would uninstall the other version of PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple php versions and want to use different version and output the same in phpinfo() type the following:
To disable the current version for example php8.1:

```
sudo a2disconf php8.1-fpm
```

To enable php7.4-fpm:

```
sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm
```

Then restart apache using this command:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

After doing this check using phpinfo() function.
Please check if you have installed php8.1-fpm or php7.4-fpm